CSS does not load when visiting website from Google search results
The title pretty much sums it up, but I am at loss as for what could be causing it.
If you go directly to https://pillser.com/probiotics/lactococcus-lactis-subsp-lactis-r1058, it loads as expected and works just fine.
However, if you Google "Lactococcus lactis subsp. lactis R1058" (doesn't matter what, as long as it finds a link to Pillser) and click on Pillser, the website loads without CSS. Refreshing the page loads CSS.
The first time it happened I thought it was a glitch, but I can replicate it consistently, so it has to be some weird setting.
I've not tried much as I cannot at the moment narrow down the cause. This is probably caused by some header that I've added to my website.

The CSS loads fine for me from both Google and from your direct link. Have you tried loading this in an incognito window, to confirm no extensions are interfering with your page load?

I am starting to think this is an issue with Cloudflare. Cloudflare is sending early hints based on the Link headers. It appears like every time I make a deployment that changes the hash of CSS, for a short time (like a few requests) Cloudflare sends early hints about wrong CSS. It doesn't fully explain why page loads without CSS because even if hash doesn't match, rules should still match.

That's so weird. I can almost consistently replicate this. And it happens only when going from google.com to Pillser

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? - Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Did you figure anything out? I’ve got the same issue it’s so bizarre. Only happens on Chrome on Android. Chrome on iOS is fine, Firefox on Android is fine.
